# How to add a view in between action bar title bar and action bar tabs?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I got a requirement to show a date picker in between the action bar title bar and the action bar tabs .Is this possible actually.If yes please suggest.

Please see the attachement.

[image: Date picker b/w tabs and action bar]

Thanks In Advance

Comment: You do not have action bar tabs in that image. You can either have action bar tabs *or* some custom navigation view, not both.

Comment: Thanks, but actually the tabs that are shown at bottom will be basically my action bar tabs and the blue bar at top is my action bar title bar.So in that case when I click on the date part on the action bar I should move the tabs down and show the date picker between them.I believe this is clear now.